# Libel of website

Tags: libel, defamation

Is it possible to libel a website such as *Craigslist* or *Facebook* in a work of fiction? For example, if one were to write about a fictional character who had an interaction with another character, and it depicted the website in an unflattering light, would that be actionable? Or is it necessary in a work of fiction to make *all* names anonymous?

Comment: While it may be possible to be prosecuted for a defamatory statement in a work of fiction, it seems rather unlikely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes

> Defamation is the communication of a false statement that harms the reputation of an individual person, **business**, **product**, group, government, religion, or nation.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defamation

Comment: But this is a work of fiction. The company in the work is therefore fictionalized. If the work makes a false statement about a company wouldn't one also have to show that the statement was intended to apply to the real company? Otherwise there's no harm.

Comment: @phoog libel is *all* about fiction - if what you say is true (non-fiction) then you have an ironclad defence

Comment: That is true, but it doesn't address my point.

Comment: @phoog if it harms the reputation of that business - then yes. Intention doesn't matter - the plaintiff would need to show actual damage to reputation.

Comment: @phoog I think the idea of "damage to reputation" resolved the issue for me. also see:  https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1557/can-fiction-fail-to-be-defamatory-if-it-is-less-bad-than-the-actual-facts?rq=1